# How one can redirect to the external url in java

Tags: java, url, redirect

I apologize if i am coming a bit ignorant here.  I am a newbie to java. I am searching how to redirect to a url using java. In PHP we can use header method like

```
header("Location:https://www.google.com");
```

How to do that in java?

Explanation:

I am making REST GET API call from PHP to java. In java i am getting Id from the call made which can be filename for an image. I want to redirect to that url/image.

Comment: where do you want this "redirect" logic, in a servlet, in a bean? do you use any MVC framework, answer depends on these.

Comment: Redirects work the same in all programming languages: send a 30x status code and a location header. The preferred way to send headers in your app depends on what you're using though.

Answer (score 0):

**You can use the RedirectView. Refer this [JavaDoc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/4.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/view/RedirectView.html)**

View that redirects to an absolute, context relative, or current request relative URL

`@RequestMapping(value = "/redirect", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView method() {
        return new ModelAndView(new RedirectView("http://www.google.com"));
    }`

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, including an explanation really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion